# Web based code editor - (smooth) vertical div resizing problem

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, mouseevent

I'm building a web based editor which has a console panel at bottom (like eclipse etc). I've been trying (unsuccessfully) for the past two days to implement the `resize functionality` -the user can grab a splitter between the editor and the console and resize their heights.

But I've not been able to make the resizing operation smooth. It works only if the user *slowly* drags the splitter, if he does it fast (like we all do when we resize) it fails. :(

Here's a small portion of my code: http://pastie.org/2324838 (save in file and launch in browser).

I'm targeting IE 7+, Firefox 3.6+, Chrome and Safari 4+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest altering your mouse events so that it doesn't stop dragging when the mouse is outside of the splitter, only when the person releases the mouse button. This will mean if the person moves the mouse quickly the splitter should still be able to catch up.

Comment: Have you tried it without having mouseover events trigger dragging off? Because that could trigger after you've moved out and then the splitter catches up. Really you only need to turn it on when the mouse clicks, and turn it off on mouseup.

Comment: That helps a bit. I've removed the `onmouseout` event. The resizing is considerably smoother now. Thanks to you! :) But it's still not as smooth as eclipse or SO question editor. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm, I don't have an environment to test this on at the moment as I'm at work using IE6 (don't ask) it could be related to how quickly the browser you're using will actually refresh the movement. In which case this isn't something you can fix. Test how it works in different browsers to get a better idea.

Comment: Sorry for deleting the first comment, I accidently added it. I'm not using the mouseover event in my code. Right now, I'm using only three events : `onmousedown`, `onmousemove` and `onmouseup`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. But it seems that SO editor resizing works across all browsers smoothly. I'll try to find out a way. :) Sbm007: Okay, thanks in advance.